# new post is not getting saved in db

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, axios

I made a post endpoints to save some data , i am sending description as String , author id , and image as buffer , but when i keep the image in my axios payload , its not getting saved in database

Endpoints

```
router.post(
  '/posts',
  isAuthenticated,
  upload.single('image'),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { desc } = req.body;
      const author = req.user._id;
      const postData = { description, author };
      if (req.file) {
        postData.image = {
          data: req.file.buffer,
          contentType: req.file.mimetype,
        };
      }
     
      const post = await post.create(postData);

      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(author, {
        $push: { posts: post._id },
      });
      res.status(201).send({ post });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send({ message: 'Server Error' });
    }
  }
);
```

//api call

```
 try {
    const res = await axios.post(`/social-posts`, {
      description: postData.postDescription,
      image: postData.image,
    });
    console.log(res.data);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
```

req body

```
postData :  {
  description: 'fssdf',
  author: new ObjectId("6402e6828bcdfc719f2da54a"),
  image: {
    data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 0d 0d 0d 0d 0e 0d 0e 10 10 0e 14 16 13 16 14 1e 1b 19 19 1b 1e 2d 20 22 20 ... 266863 more bytes>,
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  }
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting in your client and server?